# CSS not updating

Tags: css, updating

In desperation I have tried editing, changing, the colours of various backgrounds directly in the style.css, instead of custom.css or child theme, of hueman wp theme for www.toniallenauthor.co.uk and got zero effect. Tried in child theme too. No change. I want to change the greys to white yet even when I change all greys in the whole stylesheet to #fff or #ffffff, update file, refresh page I get nothing, for a week now. So I figured it was the cache but shift f5 and other computers gave nothing.

I inserted the developer's suggestion of

```
`.entry .wp-caption { background: #ffffff; } `
```

into the child and as custom.css to no effect. Found the line in the stylesheet

```
` .entry .wp-caption { background: #f1f1f1; max-width: 100%; margin-bottom: 14px; padding-top: 5px; text-align: center; } `
```

and changed the `f1f1f1` to `ffffff`. Nothing.

Somebody said sometimes the host can have a cache but they deny anything at their end... so I am at a total loss. The page still changes using the WP editor but my tinkering in css gives no changes (we need custom css to make the theme lose the greys). Anybody got ideas, please?

Comment: Is this WordPress?  If so, are you using a caching plugin (like W3 Total Cache)?  Or, is the site behind CloudFlare?  Or, are you using a CDN?  All of these things can cause the site to load a cached version of the stylesheets, regardless of what you do to the stylesheet, resulting in much hair loss and frustration.

Comment: Have you tried adding <META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache"> to the html head section? Google it...

Comment: @DJones - way off.  That's not going to help at all.

Comment: Thanks Cale, the question is not much much to go off!

Comment: Yes, Wordpress, hence WP Hueman theme. Thanks but I have changed something else so I now know it is not the cache... it is that the colour is a png image, as answered below. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

The background grey is an image

```
.col-3cm .main-inner {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("img/sidebar/s-left.png") repeat-y scroll left 0;
    padding-left: 340px;
    padding-right: 260px;
}
```

(line 340 of style.css)

I assume it is this rather than the caching that is your problem.

If not, try going directly to the style sheet's URL and making sure you can see your changes there.  If it is a caching issue, this will be an old version.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. I believe that is the problem. Not cache, confirmed. The developer says "The sidebar:

@ media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
.s2-expand .s2 { background: #f0f0f0; }
}
@ media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 960px) {
.s1-expand .s1 { background: #f0f0f0; }
}
@ media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
.sidebar { background: #f0f0f0; }
}
Then you'd also need to edit /img/sidebar/s-left.png and /img/sidebar/s-right-s2.png and save them with your color"   So I will try that. Thanks again.